# PCB 6-layer stackup problem

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-layers

I'm currently designing a PCB with double side components and I'm limited to 6 layers max. The project has couple of MCUs at 84 MHz. There are USART, I2C, SPI, some analogue lines and high-power lines in the design but not any high-speed lines. There are also some very short RF lines for antennas.

The problem is due to the high density and limited size of the PCB I can't use this stackup: S-G-S-S-P-S
At some parts of the PCB specially around the high pin count MCUs there's need for signal lines to go through the ground or power plane.

Also all the power electronics and switching components are on the back side.

This is the stackup properties provided by the PCB manufacturer:
[image]

So my main concern is if routing some signal lines through the power/ground plane will cause me problems or not?

Comment: If you take care it should not be a problem. How experienced are you are PCB layout?

Comment: if you need to cut the plane, track it around the edge to ensure a continous gnd plane

Comment: PCB designers route signals on power and ground layers all the time.  The key is understanding what you're doing and ensuring that signal integrity is maintained.

Comment: @JonRB Thanks, I have already done that.

Comment: @Andyaka I have started couple years back and have designed handful of professional PCBs, so I'm not an expert but I'm tiring to get there.

Comment: @jwh20 I used to do it as well until a year ago I read couple of papers talking about how bad it could be and it's best to avoid it.

Comment: You included the column with copper cores in the stackup, which makes me wonder if you are using copper cores or not. Can you clarify?

Comment: @bobflux Sorry for the confusion; Yes I am using  copper cores for inner layers

Comment: So if the copper cores count as layers, that's a bit like a 8 layer board? But L2/L3, and L4/L5 have copper core sandwiched between them, so they'll have pretty high capacitance to this copper, right?

Comment: @bobflux I believe so; The stackup properties is not chosen by me since the manufacturer only offers this one for six layer PCBs.

Comment: That changes the situation quite a bit because if there is a slab of copper between your signals and your ground plane, then the signals will be referenced to the slab of copper and not really to the ground plane...

Comment: @bobflux I think I can change it so that it's not copper anymore which was my original assumption. Also I can't connect or use the copper cores so I'm not really sure why they are doing it.

Comment: That's an important question, PCBs with copper cores are much more expensive than without, so there better be a good reason to have them.  Also will there be special requirements for drilling vias?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I will make sure that cores are not copper. Yes, there are no buried vias no blind vias and  the minimum drilling diametere is 0.2mm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3 basic rules

Rule #1: Bandwidth is not the clock speed rather the rise time f-3dB=0.35/Tr (10~90%) so you probably  want thinner dielectric than normal for lower impedance tracks

- this helps keep track/gap <= 5 mil  (127 um) and < matched via impedance which raises L but thinner dielectrics raises C to maintain Z^2=L/C   Also  3 mil (64um) track/gap is doable by good shops.

Rule #2 avoid crosstalk with adjacent SS layer parallel tracks.

Rule #3: Use lots of microvias for PS layer connections to other layers grids and appropriate decoupling cap per IC. If a Microvia is 50 Ohms on a power supply that is 50 mOhms, how many do you need?  ( not depends on decoupling caps and rise time and ringing tolerance)

If you don't already have , get Saturn PCB Design Toolkit

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, all the tracks that need to be routed through planes are simple digital inputs for external sensors, so after reading all the comments and answers I believe It should be fine.

Comment: OK now try to route it on 4 layers for a cost reduction j/k that 's next year job if volume goes high

Comment: That'll be a good challenge to do if it gets to that point.

Comment: A day’s job with a good auto-router

Comment: Can you recommend me one ?

Comment: I always did it better than the ones that I have used earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Experienced PCB designers DO NOT route signals on power and ground layers all the time.
They just don't do it unless there are no other ways to complete the routing.

You might need a lot of vias to complete your routing.

Reduce the size of your vias.

In high density boards I used the following via:

```
copper pads on top = 0.45 mm
drill = 0.15 mm
copper pads in inner layers = 0.45 (*)
copper pads on bottom = 0.45 mm
```

(*) Whenever I can, I enlarge inner pads 0.55 mm to make the PCB manufacture happy.

There's no extra cost to pay for these vias. They fit their standard manufacturing flow.

Comment: Thanks, I used to route signals on plane layers only if I had to, but after reading some papers about how bad it could be I avoided it completely and changed the layout or increased the layer count whenever I could.

Comment: Unless you plan to go to an EMC notified body for CE or UL compliance tests, don't go mad to complete your routing.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I have been warned many times about the importance of routing back when I was studding, so I do some times try to go over the top.